# Uncaught TypeError: "Absolute" not defined. Absolute is the positioning of the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

So I am trying to make a build-your-own-belt application with HTML5 Canvas and FabricJS. I had everything working up to the point I needed to stack the canvases on top of each other.

I changed the .canvas-wrapper position to absolute with an !important identifier to override any other positioning, but although it stacks the canvas, now when I click on any of the buttons it gives me an uncaught error, and says "absolute" is not defined. Since absolute is a parameter of position, I have no clue why it's treating it as a function

[Here](https://github.com/Nobody-Inhere/BuildaBelt2) is the github

Thanks!

Comment: I'll try to help. Are you working with `ToggleButton_backup2.html`. If so I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: showMore2 is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

Comment: Please deploy your project somewhere. You can try https://pages.github.com/ as you already use gitHub and have no backend. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the error locally.

Comment: Hi! First of all, thank you so much for helping me! I really appreciate it.

Second, I am working off BuildABelt-Beta-1.html; it should be right there with all the other stuff.